# Wordpress header template not updating code

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress theme locally. At some point all of the sudden changes to my header.php template stopped showing up on the site. A change in any other file is visible. I believe this started happening after I played around with Appeareance->Menu.

What I've done so far:

1. Made sure it's the right file, right path - yes
2. Cleared browser cache
3. added define( 'WP_CACHE', false ); in wp-config.php
4. erased all the code in the header.php file - no change, website looks normal so I undo the erase
5. removed get_header() from page.php - the website got ugly, put it back on - the website looks ok but still no changes visible from header.php (I have a huge `<h1>blah blah</h1>` in there)
6. rolled back a few commits back - still nothing
7. switched to another theme and then back to my theme - still no changes to header.php
8. performed `rm -rf on wp-content/cache/*` - still nothing
9. checked my theme on a different WordPress install - MY CHANGE IS VISIBLE, but I want it where it was so far so that doesn't solve my issue but it does seem to be some cache issue after all if it shows up in another install.

What else can I do? I've been out of ideas for a few days now.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out (actually my programming duck did). It was a plugin (Elementskit Light) causing this strange behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You might've activated the Header from ElementsKit. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a37N.png)

You can simply turn off the Header. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7VmQ.png)

But if you like to keep it activated and also need some additional custom code. Then ElementsKit also provides some hooks you can use.

These hooks are:

```
// Before Header
do_action( 'elementskit/template/before_header' );


// After Header
do_action( 'elementskit/template/after_header' );


// Before Footer
do_action( 'elementskit/template/before_footer' );


// After Footer
do_action( 'elementskit/template/after_footer' );
```